# Display tweets on a page in Django using Tweepy

Tags: python, django, twitter, tweepy

I'm new to the Django and Python.
I'm trying to create a Django app display on a page a streaming of Tweets from an account filtered by an ash tag (for the moment hardcoded).

That s my view.py

```
 from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
 from tweepy import OAuthHandler
 from tweepy import Stream
 from django.http import HttpResponse

 consumer_key="XXXXX"
 consumer_secret="XXXXX"

 access_token="XXXXXX"
 access_token_secret="XXXXX"

class StdOutListener(StreamListener):

def on_data(self, data):
    print data
    return True

def on_error(self, status):
    print status

if __name__ == '__main__':
     l = StdOutListener()
     auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
     auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

stream = Stream(auth, l)
stream.filter(track=['BT'])


 def index(request):
  return HttpResponse("try")
```

I have obviously my consumer_key, consumer_secret, acess_token and acess_token_secret edited.
In my urls.py I have

```
 from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
 from showTweets import views

 urlpatterns = patterns('',
     url(r'^$', views.index, name='index')
 )
```

And now ok if I go to the index is printing out my "try".
But I d like to print out the StdOutListener class thats the one printing my tweets, I'm sure that is working because from terminal I go in that directory running

```
 python urls.py
```

it s displaying the tweets streaming on my terminal.
But how do I display my streaming on my index page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are at the testing / practicing stage, your should use the internal django web server which can be accessed by:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

This will start up a server on port 8000 which you can access at `http://127.0.0.1:8000`. If the site isn't on your local machine simply add the IP address yu want the server to run on:

```
python manage.py runserver 192.168.1.1
```

I'm sorry if this sounds cheeky, but have you gone through the django tutorial at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/?  This is one of the first things that is mentioned in that tutorial, so if you haven't gone through it then you would benefit enormously from doing so.

Also you don't need the first line in that view (`from django.db import models`).  I'd tell you why, but the docs explain it much better than I could.

Comment: I went thought the tutorial and I have my app running at http://127.0.0.1:8000/showTweets/ and show me my "try" (which is the index of the app) but I d like to print the streaming

Comment: Then move the code from your `if __name__ == '__main__':` function into your index view and put the output of the stream into a variable so you can then pass it to the HttpResponse for output. I've pasted an example at http://pastebin.com/90exSpsh. I haven't used tweepy so I'm unsure if this will work as expected. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/intro/tutorial03/#write-views-that-actually-do-something on how to do this.  And just to repeat, I'd advise going through the full tutorial before you attempt to go any further with your app. It will save you a lot of time and frustration.

Answer (score -1):

What's the function of this line of code.
 def index(request):
  return HttpResponse("try")

I think that's the problem. U set the index function to return 'try' => httpresponse is 'try'.